# Azure IoT Device Provisioning Service: Empty Logs

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-dps

I'm trying to provision a device with Azure IoT DPS via an X.509 certificate. This currently fails with a 401 status code so I would like to consult the DPS logs to determine what is going on.

I have followed the [troubleshooting instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/iot-dps/how-to-troubleshoot-dps) and created diagnostic settings for my DPS, selecting "allLogs" and "Send to Log Analytics workspace".

Now, after trying to provision the device (and receive the 401 status code) once again, I try to query the logs:

[image]

but they are empty! However, when I check attestation attempts under "Metrics" my provisioning attempts do show up. Why are the logs empty?

Comment: Did you create the X.509 certificate locally or in Azure using Azure Activity I am able to trace the [logs](https://i.imgur.com/d8OMwO6.png). I am unable to create X.509 through local  PowerShell and [verify it](https://i.imgur.com/iR6KgKx.png)

Comment: Are you getting the 401 error while fetching the logs too. 
-> AzureActivity are for Audit and compliance , Resource ,management , Cost analysis.
Using [Azure Activity](https://i.imgur.com/Fm1VSFe.png) I was able to get the of certificates details and logs .
-> AzureDiagnostics are for Configuration changes,Service updates and Billing changes .
using [Azure Diagnotics](https://i.imgur.com/jn4QU3Q.png) I was able to the Configuration Details only I searched [cer](https://i.imgur.com/GMxiyLY.png) .

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to find X.509 certificate details with a [(activitysubstatus)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npKB5.png) status code to consult the DPS logs were found under Azure Activity.

Adding to the @Naveen inputs.

[image]

- I created [Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service (DPS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H47G7.png) and [Log Analytics workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwxXW.png) under same resource group to added Diagnostic settings In DPS.

[image]

- Select the respective Time Zone of the DPS you created.

[image]

- using Azure Activity category value in DPS.

[image]

- using Azure Diagnostics category value in DPS.

[image]

- using Azure Diagnostics in Log Analytics workspace.

[image]

- In Azure Diagnostics I searched the log related to certificate.

[image]

- In Azure Activity I searched the log related to certificate of DPS and able to find.

[image]